# Port Forwarding Using iptables on Ubuntu

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, ubuntu-12.04

[image: This is the scenario]

I have configured a web-server in MUX. Now I want to access that web-server from Internet. Ubuntu box has two interfaces, One is connected to WAN (Public IP) and another one is connected to MUX (Private IP). MUX has no option to insert default gateway.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 -d 103.x.x.x --dport 8001 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:8080
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2 --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8081 -m conntrack -ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This looks pretty complicated. I want to learn some of it. Do you know some nice documentation I can refer to?

Comment: Use an irc client and connect to irc.freenode.net   #iptables

Comment: @val0x00ff Is it any problem If I use `-m state --state` instead of `m conntrack --ctstate`?

Comment: @user141610  The difference between the two is explained here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack