# Why the firewall seems to work intermittently?

Tags: centos, firewall

I've this iptables rules on first server which has the role of a client connecting to a second mysql server through LAN adapter.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:44135]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  4 20:33:41 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb  4 20:33:41 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [76:10856]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [11:734]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11:734]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Feb  4 20:33:41 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Wed Feb  4 20:33:41 2015
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2739:2511918]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2739:2511918]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1913:165876]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1913:165876]
COMMIT
```

What's happening is that as soon as I do:

```
service iptables restart
```

it seems that all the MYSQL connections to a second server works correctly but only for a small period of time, usually 1-2 minutes, but in this 1 -2 minutes the connections to nginx (webserver, 80 port) doesn't work. After 1-2 minutes, it happens that webserver works and MYSQL doesn't work.
Tryed iptables-save command too so far but nothing changed.

This is the firewall conf o second mysql server:

```
    *filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2785:425650]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Comment: Which CentOS version?

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the default policy to `DROP` just in case your last catch-all rule is accidentally removed; like this :

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:44135]
```

Now, on the second server.

```
-A INPUT -d 192.168.1.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

This rule matches connections whose destination is 192.168.1.1, source port from 1024 to 65535, destination port 3306 and state new or established. You're overthinking this; if you want to allow MySQL connections you just have to match on the destination port and optionally add a source and/or interface parameter if you want to lock it down to a particular source IP or interface.

```
-A INPUT -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

`lo` already has access because your first `-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` rule will match anything coming from the loopback.

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Okay now you're allowing the whole subnet, but that's already better and it should work.

```
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Same as above, loopback is already allowed anyway.

```
-A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Now you're allowing everything coming from eth1 with a destination port of 3306.

```
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Your OUTPUT policy is ACCEPT everything anyway, that rules is pointless.

I'm pretty sure your problem is because the [state module has been deprecated](https://serverfault.com/questions/358996/iptables-whats-the-difference-between-m-state-and-m-conntrack) and possibly removed, so your should use conntrack.

Recap :

First server :

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Second server :

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

This will allow all SSH connections and MySQL ones originating from eth1, 192.168.1.0/24. Feel free to change that.

Comment: I changed the iptables as described. Now the problem with MYSQL and NGINX not working at the same time disappeared but the changes continue to remain for a short period of time. After 1-2 minutes it seems that MYSQL connection terminates to work correctly. It seems like all the changes are authomatically lost after a while.